# how to set the selected item in combobox and set the equivalent value in txtfield

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jcombobox

I am trying to figure out how to set up my code so that when an option is selected in a combo box, it changes the text of a textfield as well. From what I understand it involves something called an item listener but we did not discuss anything about that in class.

there is another value that is equivalent in the value of the combobox for example juan = '123456'

i tried the event listener but still it not getting the value of combobox

someone out can help thanks in advance

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem, this will reduce the guess work and produce better response

Comment: `==` is not how you compare `String`, but, `ItemEvent#getStateChange` returns an `int` which indicates if the event describes a selection or deselection event

Comment: combo1.addItemListener(
 new ItemListener(){
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    if(event.getStateChange()=='juan'){
      def juan = '1223312123'
      }
     }
    })
   
label 'Token',bounds:[10,735,200,20]; textField id:'trackerId',text:'$juan',bounds:[170,735,200,20]

Comment: that is my code i want to put the value of in the txtfield which is 12223312123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void jComboBox1ItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            
    txt1.setText((String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem());
}
```

Comment: assuming a text field is there in your design, with variable name 'txt1'. getSelectedItem returns an object which has to be type-casted into string

Comment: Also remember, `itemChanged` may be called multiple times in short succession indicating a selection/deselection event...

Answer (score 4):

Start by taking a look at [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) and in particualr [Handling Events on a Combo Box](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners) and you should have the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) referenced as well

**For example**

[image: ComboBox]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.ListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class ComboBoxTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboBoxTest();
    }

    private JComboBox<Product> cbProduts;
    private JTextField tfSku;

    public ComboBoxTest() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                DefaultComboBoxModel<Product> productModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>();
                productModel.addElement(new Product("Bananas", "1234"));
                productModel.addElement(new Product("Apples", "56789"));
                productModel.addElement(new Product("Pears", "00001"));
                productModel.addElement(new Product("Grapes", "00002"));

                cbProduts = new JComboBox<>(productModel);
                cbProduts.setRenderer(new ProductListCellRenderer());
                tfSku = new JTextField(5);

                cbProduts.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        Product p = (Product) cbProduts.getSelectedItem();
                        if (p != null) {
                            tfSku.setText(p.getSKU());
                        } else {
                            tfSku.setText(null);
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
                frame.add(cbProduts);
                frame.add(tfSku);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Product {

        private final String description;
        private final String sku;

        public Product(String description, String sku) {
            this.description = description;
            this.sku = sku;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public String getSKU() {
            return sku;
        }

    }

    public static class ProductListCellRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

        @Override
        public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

            if (value instanceof Product) {
                value = ((Product)value).getDescription();

            }
            super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
            return this;

        }

    }

}
```